# Bind child component click handler to parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

None of the other SO answers have helped, so I think I'm missing something conceptually.

I have a Parent (Wrapper) component, and a Child (Input) component. The Parent passes a function down to the child:

```
const Wrapper = () => {
  const [dictionary, setDictionary] = useState([{ word: "init", definition: "def init" }]);

  const handleWordChange = (e, value) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    /// IS NEVER TRIGGERED
  };

  return (
    <Input setDictionary={{ setDictionary }} onChange={handleWordChange} />
  )
}
```

The child component handles its own state, but is supposed to update the Parent props by calling the setDictionary function:

```
const Input = props => {
  const [definition, setDefinition] = useState("");
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    const { setDictionary } = props.setDictionary;
    e.preventDefault();
    setDictionary([{ word, definition }]);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        name='word'
        onChange={e => setWord(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setWord("")}
        placeholder='Word'
        type='text'
        value={word}
      />

      <input
        name='definition'
        onChange={e => setDefinition(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setDefinition("")}
        placeholder='Definition'
        type='text'
        value={definition}
      />
      <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>    
  )
}
```

Other answers I have seen suggest to pass a callback to the Child (setDictionary), but the onChange handler is never called on change. I've also tried to use onSubmit instead.

How do I successfully update `dictionary`? 
I know the above creates a dependency of the Child to the Parent, is there a better programmatic way to achieve this, considering that I eventually need to pass down `dictionary` to a 2nd child?

Comment: While I enjoyed and accepted your answer I'd like to recommend going easy on the lecturing about timeliness. Most of us have professional lives and other important matter, and a response within 24 hours seems very acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign child's `onChange()` event handler this way.

Instead, you refer to child event handlers as props and bind parent callbacks to those props.

The concept is known as [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).

Complete live-demo of your use case you may find below:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { useState } = React
      
const Input = ({onInput}) => {
  const [word, setWord] = useState(''),
        [definition, setDefinition] = useState('')
  return (
        <form onSubmit={e => (e.preventDefault(), onInput(word, definition))}>
          <label>
            Word: 
            <input onChange={({target:{value}}) => setWord(value)} />
          </label>
          <label>
            Definition: 
            <input onChange={({target:{value}}) => setDefinition(value)} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
  )
}

const List = ({list}) => (
  <ul>
    {
      list.map(({word,definition},key) => <li {...{key}}><strong>{word}</strong> - {definition}</li>)
    }
  </ul>
)

const Parent = () => {
  const [dictionary, setDictionary] = useState([]),
        onDicionaryItemSubmit = (word,definition) => setDictionary([...dictionary, {word,definition}])
   return (
    <div>
      <Input onInput={onDicionaryItemSubmit} />
      <List list={dictionary} />
    </div>
   )
}

render (
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. I really like the `onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setWord(value)}` destructuring of the event. Never thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not even triggering onChange passed to component

```
  <Input setDictionary={{ setDictionary }} onChange={handleWordChange} />
```

you have to do exactly as you named the prop like props.onChange

```
//there is no props.onChange here in this component

const Input = props => {
  const [definition, setDefinition] = useState("");
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    const { setDictionary } = props.setDictionary;
    e.preventDefault();
    setDictionary([{ word, definition }]);
    //like here
    props.onChange(any arguments);

  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        name='word'
        onChange={e => setWord(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setWord("")}
        placeholder='Word'
        type='text'
        value={word}
      />

      <input
        name='definition'
        onChange={e => setDefinition(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setDefinition("")}
        placeholder='Definition'
        type='text'
        value={definition}
      />
      <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>    
  )
}
```

If i rename

```
 <Input setDictionary={{ setDictionary }} onInputChanged={handleWordChange} />
```

i'd call it like

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    const { setDictionary } = props.setDictionary;
    e.preventDefault();
    setDictionary([{ word, definition }]);
    //like here
    props.onInputChanged(any arguments);

  }
```

Comment: Isn't the `onChange={handleWordChange}` optional anyway? Setting the new dictionary state should happen in the Child via `setDictionary([{ word, definition }])` but the state in the parent Wrapper never updates. Do I need to not set parent state in the child, and just do it in the parent within the handleWordChange function?

Comment: you're using two handlers here , one for setDictionary and the other for handleWordChange. If you call only one in child. how do you expect both to be fired.

Comment: handleWordChangeis passed to onChange as its value. When onChange is never accessed in child, why'd it trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
//there is not props.onChange here in this component

const Input = props => {
  const [definition, setDefinition] = useState("");
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    const { setDictionary } = props.setDictionary;
    e.preventDefault();
    setDictionary([{ word, definition }]);
    //like here
    props.onChange(any arguments);

  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        name='word'
        onChange={e => {
          setWord(e.target.value)
         props.onChange();
        }}
        onFocus={() => setWord("")}
        placeholder='Word'
        type='text'
        value={word}
      />

      <input
        name='definition'
        onChange={e => {
    setDefinition(e.target.value)
              props.onChange();
    }}
        onFocus={() => setDefinition("")}
        placeholder='Definition'
        type='text'
        value={definition}
      />
      <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>    
  )
}
```

Use parent onChange() method in your Input Component than it will be triggered if you didn't call that method than how it will triggered i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Error:- not calling `onChange` function in `<Input/>` and setting state of dictionary in `<Wrapper />`. 
This is the working solution of your query.

```js
const {useState} = React;
const Wrapper = () => {
  const [dictionary, setDictionary] = useState([
    { word: "computer", definition: "an electronic device for storing and processing data" }
  ]);

  const handleWordChange = (e, value) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let updateDictionary = [...dictionary];
    updateDictionary.push(value);
    setDictionary(updateDictionary);
    // console.log(updateDictionary);
    /// IS NEVER TRIGGERED
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Input onChange={handleWordChange} />
      {dictionary.length > 0 ? (
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>WORD</th>
            <th>DEFINITION</th>
          </tr>
          {dictionary.map(datum => (
            <tr>
              <td>{datum.word}</td>
              <td>{datum.definition}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </table>
      ) : null}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Input = props => {
  const [definition, setDefinition] = useState("");
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onChange(e, { word, definition });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        name="word"
        onChange={e => setWord(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setWord("")}
        placeholder="Word"
        type="text"
        value={word}
      />

      <input
        name="definition"
        onChange={e => setDefinition(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => setDefinition("")}
        placeholder="Definition"
        type="text"
        value={definition}
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```